# Application of Taylor approximation

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics, taylor-expansion

I need some help to understand an equality from a paper I'm currently working on.
In a simplified version it says
\begin{equation}
\ln\left(1-\frac{\int\left(1-\exp\left(- h(x) \gamma^2\right) \right)\alpha(x)dx}{\rho} \right) = -\gamma^2 \cdot \frac{\int h(x)\alpha(x)dx}{\rho} + o(\gamma^2)
\end{equation}
as $\gamma \searrow0.$

Although I see that this resembles the Maclaurin series for $\exp(x)$ and $\ln(1-x)$ a little bit, I have no idea what is going on here.
Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Just do it the brute force way. Derive the expression with respect to $\gamma$ and substitute $\gamma = 0$. Then do it one more time.